# How can i change N existing users in mysql database to aa1, aa2, aa3 and so on

Tags: mysql, sql

and also change all the passwords, for these users to "password" but also leave the user with id=1 unchanged, since that is the admin user.

Comment: Oh dear, I detect someone storing passwords as plaintext.

Comment: this is only used for testing and baselining plus performance comparison between MyISAM and InnoDB. Only ot be used internally on a test database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

`UPDATE users SET name = CONCAT('aa',id) WHERE id != 1`

but it's impossible to do it properly without your schema.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean MySQL users, but then again you mention ids, which MySQL user's don't have: You can update the `user` table in the `mysql` database. After doing so, run `flush privileges`.

The password column is stored hashed; the `password` function will compute these hashes.

Information about the `mysql.user` table is scattered throughout the documentation. One place that says a reasonable bit is http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/request-access.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this(update @N with the number you want):

```
UPDATE users, (SELECT @rowNumber := 0  ) a SET name = CONCAT('aa',@rowNumber := @rowNumber + 1) 
WHERE @rowNumber < @N
```